# Bootstrap Popover placement 'right & left' issue when manually triggered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

When there are lot of popovers, and if i want to trigger those using 'manual', then only top & bottom will display in proper position. If the placement is right or left, it is misaligned. Please have a look at this fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/6nz4u940/

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Try v1.2 Bootstrap Online</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function popit(){
      console.log("fddffdg");
      $("[data-content]").each(function () {
      $(this).attr({"data-container":"body","data-trigger":"manual","data-toggle":"popover"});
      $(this).popover('toggle');
      });
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="popit()">click me and scroll down, i wont show all popover</button>
<div class = "container" style = "padding: 100px 50px 10px;" >
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement="right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on left">

      Popover on left
   </button>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement = "top" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on top">

      Popover on top
   </button>

   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-success" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement = "bottom" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on bottom">

      Popover on bottom
   </button>

   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-warning" title = "Popover title"  
      data-container = "body" data-toggle = "popover" data-placement = "right" 
      data-content = "Some content in Popover on right">

      Popover on right
   </button>

</div>

<script>
   $(function (){
      $("[data-toggle = 'popover']").popover();
   });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes boss, just give us a second :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time, [improve the existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621552/bootstrap-popover-placement-right-left-issue) instead of just posting another. While you're waiting for "someone post a solution ASAP" you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: He's an important man, we must give him an answer even if he's not polite...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this by using the `viewport` option..

```
$("[data-content]").popover({
    trigger:"manual",
    viewport:".container"
});
```

http://codeply.com/go/Amjs267PcE